# Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: java, email, ssl

I am trying to send an email via our private smtp server here is my code

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws MessagingException {
  Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", "gi-systems.net");
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxx@gi-systems.net"));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("yyyy@hotmail.com, false));
        msg.setSubject("Password Recovery");
        msg.setText(pwd);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtps");
        t.connect("smtp.gi-systems.net", "xxxx@gi-systems.net", "mypassword");
        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        System.out.println("Response: " + t.getLastServerResponse());
        t.close();
}
```

But when i run this code i got this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gi-systems.net, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1706)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at com.mycompany.sendmail.App.SendEmail(App.java:45)
    at com.mycompany.sendmail.App.main(App.java:64)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
......
```

**Ps:** when i use gmail smtp and email address it works fine

How can i fix this exception???

Answer (score 1):

Check Following Things:

For Example Gmail.

1.

```
t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "mailID", "Password");
```

2.Properties:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  //For Gmail 'smtp.gmail.com' check carefully for Yours               
props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");//or port 465
```

*Please check for your case.*

It seems something wrong with setting properties or Authentication.

Comment: it works with gmailID but not with xxxxxx@gi-systems.com

Answer (score 1):

> unable to find valid certification path to requested target

This means that the certificate agency you use is not known. Trying with openssl gives:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.gi-systems.net:465
...
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=--/ST=France/L=Roubaix/O=OVH/OU=--/CN=ns317329.ip-37-187-133.eu/emailAddress=root@ns317329.ip-37-187-133.eu
   i:/C=--/ST=France/L=Roubaix/O=OVH/OU=--/CN=ns317329.ip-37-187-133.eu/emailAddress=root@ns317329.ip-37-187-133.eu
...
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

So you are using a self-signed certificate which of course cannot be verified by java.
I'm not sure if you can verify a self-signed certificate by fingerprint, otherwise you might need to create your own small CA (or use cacert.org or similar) and import the CA as trusted like explained in http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/MakeSeammailWorkingWithYourSelfsignedCertificates

Comment: This helped me identify the actual hostname that the (wild) certificate is configured for. So I instead used that name instead of the www.xxx.tld domain name

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the port address and host are accurate. I think for the SMTPS, generally 587 or 465 port is used

Thanks

Comment: But you need to specify the port in the method `connect` too!

Comment: Are you sure about the connection to SMTP host in your network. Telnet to the port. Refer http://www.simplescripts.de/smtp-check-port-25-telnet-command.htm and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119
Also check with your network administrator or mail service provider for the connection details

Answer (score 0):

Add the protocol.

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
```

Regards.

Comment: `SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtps");` isn't doing the same you suggested?

Comment: Transport != Session. The props are for the session, not for the transport only.